# CheckBox Background color in GridView

Tags: .net, wpf, gridview, checkbox

ListView GridView with TextBlock and CheckBox

Problem is background

If I click on the TextBlock that row receives Background of LightBlue
And the Background of LightBlue if removed from any other row
That is the behavior I want

Problem is with the CheckBox
When I click the CheckBox the background of LightBlue   is not removed from other rows
And when I move the mouse off that row the LightBlue background goes away
I want the CheckBox background to color like the TextBlock 
It is like the CheckBox is eating the click to select the row

Tried Focusable="False" and "True" on the CheckBox and that did not fix it.

```
<Style.Resources>
    <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightBlue"/>
    <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="LightBlue" />
</Style.Resources>

<GridViewColumn Width="100">
    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="UserID" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    </GridViewColumnHeader>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding Path=UserID, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
<GridViewColumn Width="45">
    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Select" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    </GridViewColumnHeader> 
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="" IsChecked="{Binding Path=On, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      IsEnabled="{Binding Path=OnEnabled, Mode=OneWay}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: Basically you want everything to be LightBlue, right???

Comment: @devhedgehog The whole row for the selected row.  Problem is the check box basically does not take or hold select.

Comment: Explain better what you are looking for.

Comment: @devhedgehog What part is not clear?  When I click textblock it colors and the other rows uncolor.  When I click the checkbox other rows do not uncolor.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix I used was to bind the SelectedItem and in the CheckBox assign it
See searchItemUsrFld.FieldDefUsrFldUsrOnSelected = this;
The CheckBox was eating the Click so ListView was not getting the Click

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SearchItem.FieldDefUsrFldUsrOnSelected}"

public Boolean? On
{   // this does not get saved to db as it is just for search
    get
    {
        return on;
    }
    set
    {
        if (on == value) return;
        on = value;
        searchItemUsrFld.FieldDefUsrFldUsrOnSelected = this;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("On");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see now you change the color when a ListViewItem gets focus.

When clicking on TextBlock the TextBlock is not receiving focus but instead it is its parent and in your case it is the ListViewItem. That is why its working with TextBlock. Though when you click on CheckBox the CheckBox may receive focus and so the parent which is ListViewItem doesnt get focus. Futhermore its not changing the color.

The solution is listen to GotFocus event at ListViewItem level and set the color in code inside handler.